# ConoHa APIでjsonデータをリクエスト

Tags: python, python3, api, conoha

サーバーを提供しているconohaでAPIを利用しようと試みておりますが躓いております。
やりたいことはAPIを利用したサーバーの追加です。調べたところ下の手順で作るものだと思われます。

1. トークン発行　https://www.conoha.jp/docs/identity-post_tokens.html
2. VM追加　https://www.conoha.jp/docs/compute-create_vm.html

はじめにトークンの発行ですがPOSTでJSONの送り方を調べ[このサイト](http://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/03/08/021706)を参考にして下のようなコードを書きました。

`headers={'Content-type':'application/json'}`の意味は分かりませんがとりあえず実行したところ、以下のエラーが出ました。

> dict object has no attribute encode

`encode('utf-8')`を消してみると以下のエラーが出ます。

> Can't concat bytes to str

初心者なので何か基本的なことが間違えているかもしれないです。
また、トークン発行した後どのような作業をして2のVM追加に至るのか少しでいいので道筋を教えていただけると幸いです。

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url="https://identity.tyo1.conoha.io/v2.0"
method="POST"
headers={
'Content-type':'application/json'
}

json_str={"auth": {
"passwordcredentials": {
"username": "aaa",
"password": "bbb"
},
"tenantid": "ccc"
}
}

req = urllib.request.Request(url=url,headers=headers, data=json_str.encode('utf-8'))
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/119605

Comment: json _strが辞書型だったので文字列に変更したところ、エラーの内容が下のように変わりました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　urllib.error http.Error 405 Not Allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

複数の問題点があります。

- 参照先のサイトに従うのであれば、`json_str` は辞書ではなく文字列にすべきです。今回の場合、`json_str = '{"a":1}'` のようにシングルクオートで全体を囲えば良いです。
- リクエスト先の URI が異なります。やりたいことに応じて、ConoHa のドキュメントに書いてある "Request URL" をご参照ください。また、[ドキュメント](https://www.conoha.jp/docs/identity-post_tokens.html)の以下にも注意してください。

  > ※エンドポイントURLにつきましては、お客様環境によって異なりますので、コントロールパネルにてご確認の上ご利用ください。
- 変数 `method` が、初期値を代入された後使われていません。今回は単に要らないです。
- コピー・ペースト時の問題かもしれませんが、Python のプログラムはインデントに意味があります。それぞれの行の左側にある空白を消さないようにしてください。

また、単に API を叩くだけであれば、ご参照先のブログにも書いてあるように urllib.request ではなく [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) を使った方が見通しが良いと思います。たとえば今回の場合、今行っているのが GET なのか POST なのかもコードから読み取りづらいですが、Requests だとこれが改善されます。日本語だと Qiita の[この記事](https://qiita.com/sqrtxx/items/49beaa3795925e7de666)の解説が分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。いくつかコードの間違いして頂き感謝します。また、urllibを使わない方法ですね。大変参考になります。
APIを過去に使用したことがないのでコード見てゆっくり勉強してみようかと思います。
一つ疑問点があります。Request URLの読み方が分からないです。
1行目はAPIのバージョンで２行目は identity serviceのエンドポントの文末に/v2.0/tokensを加えたURLにPOSTをしてください。という意味合いなのでしょうか。
Request URL
identity API v2.0
POST /v2.0/tokens

Comment: はい、そうです。Python ではなく curl を使った例ではありますが、ドキュメントの "Example" → "REQ" の部分に実際にどのような URI にアクセスする感じになるか書いてあるので、ご参照下さい。

Comment: 貴重な時間を使い回答していただき感謝します。精進します(≧▽≦)

Comment: requestsを用いる方法で第一段階のトークンの発行できました。ありがとうございます(≧▽≦)
こちらのドキュメントにはrequest jsonではなくrequest parameterも載っていたので勉強のため
parameterを使ってみたのですが400badrequestとなりました><よろしければ不適切な所ご指摘いただけないでしょうか。
https://www.conoha.jp/docs/identity-post_tokens.html

https://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=1740385821.png

Comment: 上記の質問を別スレッドで新たに質問しました。
お時間ありましたら回答よろしくお願いします。